# Define Return status code

Tags: c#

this is a very general and probably common question, but I couldn't find an answer for it in the web.

I am looking for a sensible way to create a status code for an application that can fail on some part but still succeed in other.

Lets say that I have an application runs some algorithm.
after we get the results, the app is supposed to do 3 things:

1. Sent the results in an email
2. Save the results to Db
3. send the results to another integrated foreign application.

I need to create one status code that includes status for each independent step, and can indicate of single, or multiple failures.

Is there anything that is common practice for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using flags, see [this](https://www.google.nl/search?q=C%23+flags&oq=C%23+flags&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1063j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

For example:

```
[Flags]
public enum ReturnCode
{
   RESULT1 = 0x1,
   RESULT2 = 0x2,
   RESULT3 = 0x4
}
```

And then in your return:

```
return (ReturnCode.RESULT1 | ReturnCode.RESULT3);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use Flag Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options 
{
  None    = 0,
  Option1 = 1,
  Option2 = 2,
  Option3 = 4,
  Option4 = 8
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229062(v=vs.100).aspx

Here you can find some nice examples with `.HasFlag`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx

In your case it could be something like this (and it could be expanded ofcourse, it really depends on your design and requirements):

```
[Flags]
public enum ReturnStatus
{
  NoErrors = 0,
  DBError = 1,
  ThirdPartyError = 2,
  EmailError = 4,
  EmailSend = 8 
  //This could also be an option, so i just added it here as example, but i'm a bit confused if this is used as a return status or the current state of a task
  //Example: when database failed, and the algorithm doesn't event attempts to send a mail, and when you want to rerun a task it could be usefull
}

ReturnStatus ret = ReturnStatus.DBError | ReturnStatus.EmailError;

if( ret.HasFlag(ReturnStatus.EmailError) ) {
  //Email failed to send
}
if( ret.HasFlag(ReturnStatus.DBError) ) {
  //Db save failed
}
```

Comment: Expanding on this, for multiple errors for multiple tasks, just have an object that contains each task and the enum that corresponds to it

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum where you define 0 as success and then each possible error condition as further values. This is fine when the operation is sequential i.e. if step one fails it doesn't try to do steps two and three.

If the steps are independent then you might consider using a bit encoded value to indicate the error state. Zero means success again. If bit 1 is set then step 1 failed; bit 2, step 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum for each independant step and a flag:

```
public enum MailStatus 
{
    Ok  = 1,
   Bad = 2
}

public enum DbStatus 
{
    Ok  = 4,
    Bad = 8
}

public static void Main()
{
    var mailStatus = MailStatus.Ok;
    var dbStatus = DbStatus.Ok;
    var status = (int)mailStatus | (int)dbStatus;
    // Example: we test if status matches with EmailStatus.Ok
    if ((status & (int)MailStatus.Ok) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
    }
}
```